# Add a UITabBarController to a UIViewController (Xcode 4.6)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am studying Objective-C and I started to create an App while I am learning it.
I have created a "Single View Application" with two "View Controllers" called "ViewController" and "secondViewController", after that I thought to add an "UITabBarController", so following a tutorial I used the following code in the AppDelegate.m

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

[self customizeInterface];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

UIViewController *viewController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UITabBarItem *tab1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Artists" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"artist-tab.png"] tag:1];
[viewController1 setTabBarItem:tab1];

UIViewController *viewController2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UITabBarItem *tab2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Music" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"music-tab.png"] tag:2];
[viewController2 setTabBarItem:tab2];

tabController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1,
                                 viewController2, nil];


self.window.rootViewController = tabController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
}
```

Here is the ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

If I run the application, the tab bar is working but I have a blank screen and not the ViewController I have created.
Just because I am a noob, could you please tell me how to link or show the view controllers respectively in each tab?

Please be so kind to say everything also the obvious things.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are beginner I would highly suggest you to use storyboards, that will help to manage the interface much more easier because  you will not have to code almost anything.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

I am just guessing but your problem might be that you directly `init` your view controller , you should call `initWithNibName:` method in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. The `initWithNibName:` is something that you call when you create a controller instance from a nib file.

So basically `initWithNibName:` is called when the NIB is loaded and instantiated.

I dont know your ViewContoller class names but you should change your view controllers init methods

in your app delegate.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "secondViewController.h" 


    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; // make sure on interface builder hat you Nib name is ViewController

    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[secondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];// make sure on interface builder hat you Nib name is secondViewController
```

and please use Upper Case Chars and detailed names for class name secondViewController is not good programming practice

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I forgot to tell you that I already use a storyboard, but I thought that using the previous code could be much more easier to add any further customization later, but maybe I was wrong. If I replace my lines in the code with the following two, at the start (after the load screen) the app crash.
This is what I have written:
`UIViewController *viewController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil];`

Comment: That's because in the custom class I have putted "ViewController" for the first View Controller Window and "secondViewController" for the second View Controller Window.

Comment: if you use storyboard you need change bundle=nil to `[NSBundle mainBundle]` I have edited answer look it again. and also click storyboard and click your views and make sure their Storyboard ID's matches with your class name

Comment: This is what I have now, using the updated code:
"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/meme/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/08CBEFA8-8E7F-442F-BFAC-1D1360301076/MyFirstApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'ViewController' ".

Comment: it says it can not find A nib named 'ViewController' , I am sorry but what part of this you dont understand this `click storyboard and click your views and make sure their Storyboard ID's matches with your class name` you have to set your view's IDs, custom class as same as your class names.

Comment: Sorry but I already did it, as you can see: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/195/viewcontroller.png/

I added the ViewController.m code

Comment: try to upload  your project somewhere I can look, or wait for other people answer this question, maybe my answer is wrong

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23733/discussion-between-space-dust-and-mark)

Answer (score 0):

The tabbar controller shows the views, you created in your code. That's the expected behaviour, since you are creating completely new views.

If you created "ViewController" and "secondViewController" in Interface Builder, then you'll have to load the nibs - instead of creating new views - and tell the tabbar controller to use these.

Basically you'll have to change your lines:

`UIViewController *viewController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];`

to something like

`UIViewController *viewController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"view1" bundle:nil];`

Please see `initWithNibName:bundle:` for the details.